# Как в Яндекс-картах повесить событие Update?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

В [документации](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/map.xml#event-Update) сказано, что вставить в колбек, но не пойму, синтаксис хромает или не так понял.

Вызов карты такой:

```
myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [45, 55],
    zoom: 12,
    type: 'yandex#publicMap',
    behaviors:['default', 'scrollZoom']
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй как-то так:

```
YMaps.Events.observe(myMap, myMap.Events.Update, function () {
    alert("Если видишь - сработало");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вызов карты использует api версии 2, в то время как ссылка ведет на документацию по версии 1. Если вы используете api версии 1, то создание карты выглядит так:

```
var myMap = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]);
```

а подключение обработчика так:

```
YMaps.Events.observe(myMap, myMap.Events.Update, function () {
    alert("Щелк!");
});
```

А в [api версии 2](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/Map.xml#events-summary) нет события Update.